# TCP close() vs shutdown() in Linux OS

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming

I know there are already a lot similar questions in stackoverflow, but nothing seems convincing. Basically trying to understand under what circumstances I need to use one over the other or use both.
Also would like to understand if close() & shutdown() with shut_rdwr are the same.

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs. Tnx

Answer (score 13):

Closing TCP connections has gathered so much confusion that we can rightfully say either this aspect of TCP has been poorly designed, or is lacking somewhere in documentation.

### Short answer

To do it the proper way, you should use all 3: `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`, `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` and `close()`, in this order. No, `shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)` and `close()` are not the same. Read their documentation carefully and questions on SO and articles about it, you need to read more of them for an overview.

### Longer answer

The first thing to clarify is **what you aim for**, when closing a connection. Presumably you use TCP for a higher lever protocol (request-response, steady stream of data etc.). Once you decide to "close" (terminate) connection, all you had to send/receive, you sent and received (otherwise you would not decide to terminate) - so what more do you want? I'm trying to outline what you *may* want at the time of termination:

1. to know that all data sent in either direction **reached the peer**
2. if there are any errors (in transmitting the *data in process of being sent when you decided to terminate*, as well as *after that*, and in doing *the termination itself* - which also requires data being sent/received), **the application is informed**
3. optionally, some applications want to be **non-blocking** up to and including the termination

Unfortunately TCP doesn't make these features easily available, and the user needs to understand what's under the hood and how the system calls interact with what's under the hood. A key sentence is in the `recv` manpage:

```
   When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the
   return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).
```

What the manpage means here is, orderly shutdown is done by one end (**A**) choosing to call `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`, which causes a FIN packet to be sent to the peer (**B**), and this packet takes the form of a 0 return code from `recv` inside **B**. (Note: the FIN packet, being an implementation aspect, is not mentioned by the manpage). The "EOF" as the manpage calls it, means there will be no more transmission *from A to B*, but application **B** can, and should continue to send what it was in the process of sending, and even send some more, potentially (**A** is still receiving). When that sending is done (shortly), **B** should itself call `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` to close the other half of the duplex. Now app **A** receives EOF and all transmission has ceased. The two apps are OK to call `shutdown(SHUT_RD)` to close their sockets for reading and then `close()` to free system resources associated with the socket (TODO I haven't found clear documentation taht says the 2 calls to shutdown(SHUT_RD) are sending the ACKs in the termination sequence FIN --> ACK, FIN --> ACK, but this seems logical).

Onwards to our aims, for (1) and (2) basically the application must somehow **wait** for the shutdown sequence to happen, and observe its outcome. Notice how if we follow the small protocol above, it is clear *to both apps* that the termination initiator (**A**) has sent everything to **B**. This is because **B** received EOF (and EOF is received only after everything else). **A** also received EOF, which is issued in reply to its own EOF, so **A** knows **B** received everything (there is a caveat here - the termination protocol must have a convention of who initiates the termination - so not both peers do so at once). However, the reverse is not true. After **B** calls `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`, there is nothing coming back app-level, to tell **B** that **A** received all data sent, plus the FIN (the A->B transmission had ceased!). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe at this stage **B** is in state "LAST_ACK" and when the final ACK arrives (step #4 of the 4-way handshake), concludes the close but the application is not informed **unless** it had set SO_LINGER with a long-enough timeout. SO_LINGER "ON" instructs the shutdown call to block (be performed in the forground) hence the shutdown call itself will do the waiting.

In conclusion what I recommend is to configure SO_LINGER ON with a long timeout, which causes it to block and hence return any errors. What is not entirely clear is whether it is shutdown(SHUT_WR) or shutdown(SHUT_RD) which blocks in expectation of the LAST_ACK, but that is of less importance as we need to call both.

Blocking on shutdown is problematic for requirement #3 above where e.g. you have a single-threaded design that serves all connections. Using SO_LINGER may block all connections on the termination of one of them. I see 3 routes to address the problem:

1. shutdown with LINGER, from a different thread. This will of course complicate a design
2. linger in background and either

2A. "Promote" FIN and FIN2 to app-level messages which you can read and hence wait for. This basically moves the problem that TCP was meant to solve, one level higher, which I consider hack-ish, also because the ensuing shutdown calls may still end in a limbo.

2B. Try to find a lower-level facility such as `SIOCOUTQ ioctl` described [here](http://ia800504.us.archive.org/3/items/TheUltimateSo_lingerPageOrWhyIsMyTcpNotReliable/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable.html) that queries number of unACKed bytes in the network stack. The caveats are many, this is Linux specific and we are not sure if it aplies to FIN ACKs (to know whether closing is fully done), plus you'd need to poll taht periodically, which is complicated. Overall I'm leaning towards option 1.

I tried to write a comprehensive summary of the issue, corrections/additions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets are bidirectional - you send and receive over the one socket. close() stops communication in both directions. shutdown() provides another parameter that allows you to specify which direction you might want to stop using.

Another difference (between close() and shutdown(rw)) is that close() will keep the socket open if another process is using it, while shutdown() shuts down the socket irrespective of other processes.

shutdown() is often used by clients to provide framing - to indicate the end of their request, e.g. an echo service might buffer up what it receives until the client shutdown()s their send side, which tells the server that the client has finished, and the server then replies; the client can receive the reply because it has only shutdown() writing, not reading, through its socket.

Answer (score -2):

Close will close both send and receving end of socket.If you want only sending part of socket should be close not receving part or *vice versa* you can use shutdown.

```
close()------->will close both sending and receiving end.
shutdown()------->only want to close sending or receiving.
  argument:SHUT_RD(shutdown reading end (receiving end))
           SHUT_WR(shutdown writing end(sending end))
SHUT_RDWR(shutdown both)
```