# Unable to perform TCP four-way connection-close in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I have written a cross platform file transfer tool using C language, using TCP as the transfer protocol. But I am currently encountering a problem.

That is, the TCP four-way connection-close is missing.

> My question only includes four-way connection-close in the TCP protocol.
>
> The transmission process is all normal, including file length and file hash value.

This is the sample code (which reproduces the core part of my code):

#### receiving end (Ubuntu 20.04)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
typedef struct sockaddr    SOCKADDR;
typedef struct addrinfo    ADDRINFO;
typedef struct sockaddr_in SOCKADDR_IN;

#define BLOCKLEN 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN *ipv4 = NULL;
    ADDRINFO *result = NULL; // Domain Name System structure
    ADDRINFO hints = { // IPv4
        .ai_family = AF_INET};
    FILE *fp = NULL; // File structure
    SOCKADDR *client = NULL;

    const char *host = "0.0.0.0"; // hostname
    uint64_t fileSize; // file size
    uint64_t tSize; // Single transmission size
    uint16_t port = 49281; // listen port
    uint8_t fileBuf[BLOCKLEN]; // data buffer
    uint8_t fileSizeBuf[8]; // file size buffer

    int sockfd; // listen socket

    // Name Resolution
    getaddrinfo(host, "echo", &hints, &result);

    // Initialize
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(fileBuf, 0, BLOCKLEN);
    memset(fileSizeBuf, 0, 8);
    fp = fopen("xxxxx", "wb");
    client = (SOCKADDR *)malloc(result->ai_addrlen);

    // Initialize IPv4 network structure
    ipv4 = (SOCKADDR_IN *)result->ai_addr;
    ipv4->sin_port = htons(port);

    bind(sockfd, (SOCKADDR *)&ipv4, result->ai_addrlen);
    listen(sockfd, 5);
    printf("Waiting for the client to connect...\n");
    sockfd = accept(sockfd, client, &result->ai_addrlen);

    printf("Successfully connected, starting to receive data.\n");
    // Received file size, Assign file size data to integer
    // variables.
    recv(sockfd, fileSizeBuf, 8, 0);
    memcpy(&fileSize, fileSizeBuf, 8);

    // Subtract the received length from the file length until
    // the file length becomes 0.
    for(; fileSize; fileSize -= tSize) {
        tSize = recv(sockfd, fileBuf, BLOCKLEN, 0);
        fwrite(fileBuf, 1, tSize, fp);
    }

    // Tell the client that the data has been fully received.
    send(sockfd, "done", 4, 0);

    // Release all used items before the program ends.
    fclose(fp);
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    close(sockfd);
    shutdown(sockfd, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

#### client end (Windows 10 x64 22H2)

> There is a problem with this sample code and it cannot be connected to the receiving end, but the issue I want to express is not this, so I did not fix the problem of this sample code being unable to connect.

```c
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")

#define BLOCKLEN 4096

uint64_t GetfileSize(const char *fn)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(fn, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    LARGE_INTEGER W_size;
    GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &W_size);
    
    return W_size.QuadPart;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA ws;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &ws);

    SOCKADDR_IN *ipv4 = NULL; // pointer
    ADDRINFO *result = NULL; // Domain Name System structure
    ADDRINFO hints = { // IPv4
        .ai_family = AF_INET};
    FILE *fp = NULL; // File structure

    const char *fn = "xxxxxx"; // file name
    const char *host = "47.x.x.x"; // hostname
    uint64_t fileSize; // file size
    uint16_t port = 49281; // listen port
    uint64_t quotient; // Quotient of file length divided by block size
    uint64_t leftover; // Remaining length of file
    char fileBuf[BLOCKLEN]; // data buffer
    char fileSizeBuf[8]; // file size buffer
    char message[4]; // Transfer message

    SOCKET sockfd; // listen socket

    // Initialize
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(fileBuf, 0, BLOCKLEN);
    memset(fileSizeBuf, 0, 8);
    fileSize = GetfileSize(fn);
    fp = fopen(fn, "rb");
    memcpy(fileSizeBuf, &fileSize, 8);

    // Name Resolution
    getaddrinfo(host, "echo", &hints, &result);

    // Initialize IPv4 network structure
    ipv4 = (SOCKADDR_IN *)result->ai_addr;
    ipv4->sin_port = htons(port);

    // Connect to the receiving end
    connect(sockfd, (SOCKADDR *)ipv4, result->ai_addrlen);

    // Send file size data
    send(sockfd, fileSizeBuf, 8, 0);

    quotient = fileSize / BLOCKLEN;
    leftover = fileSize % BLOCKLEN;
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < quotient; ++i) {
        fread(fileBuf, 1, BLOCKLEN, fp);
        send(sockfd, fileBuf, BLOCKLEN, 0);
    }
    if(leftover) {
        fread(fileBuf, 1, leftover, fp);
        send(sockfd, fileBuf, leftover, 0);
    }

    recv(sockfd, message, 4, 0);

    fclose(fp);
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Overall, the receiving end executes specific receiving code based on the size of the file sent by the sending end.

The sender sends all the file data in one go.

After the transmission is completed, the receiving end will send a signal to the sending end to indicate that the reception is complete.

The following is a screenshot from Wireshark.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: TCP uses a 3-way handshake, not a 4-way handshake, and based on the packet captures that has already happened.

Comment: You don't have any kind of error checking in the code you show. It the code you show modified from your actual code, to remove the error checking for brevity? Or is it your actual code, and you really need to add error checking?

Comment: @dbush I refer to the 4 packet confirmations performed when the TCP protocol ends the connection. I am not sure what the name is called in English, I am very sorry. If you know, please let me know and I will modify the questions raised. thank you.

Comment: By the way, are your server program running in privileged mode? The `echo` protocol is using port `7`, which is a privileged port.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Due to my actual code being very long, the code displayed on this page is an example that I just spent 30 minutes hastily writing.

Comment: Like TCP network stacks can shorten the three-way connection handshake to a two-way, by combining flags, it can do the same with the four-way connection-close handshake.

Comment: yes, server is root.

Answer (score 2):

> I refer to the 4 packet confirmations performed when the TCP protocol ends the connection.

You are referring to the `FIN`|`ACK`|`FIN`|`ACK` close sequence when shutting down the TCP connection gracefully.

In your Ubuntu code, this logic is backwards:

> ```
> close(sockfd);
> shutdown(sockfd, 2);
> ```

You need to call `shutdown()` *before* `close()`.  `shutdown()` will close down the communication channel and send the `FIN` packet, but otherwise leave the socket allocated.  `close()` will actually free the socket, but it will not send a `FIN` for you. See: [TCP close() vs shutdown() in Linux OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208236/).

What you *should* be doing instead is call `shutdown()` first to send a `FIN`, *then* call `recv()` until there is nothing left to read (ie, when `FIN` is received, or an error occurred), *then* call `close()`.  This is the best way to gracefully close a TCP connection.

Your Windows code doesn't suffer from that issue because it is not calling `shutdown()` at all, it is relying on `closesocket()` to perform an *implicit* shutdown in the background for you (which differs from how `close()` behaves on other platforms). See: [Graceful Shutdown, Linger Options, and Socket Closure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/graceful-shutdown-linger-options-and-socket-closure-2).

Even your Windows code *should* be using the same `shutdown()`+`recv()`+`closesocket()` approach to gracefully close a TCP connection.

---

On a side note:

Your Ubuntu code is leaking the listening socket, as it is overwriting the initial `sockfd` value with the `accept()`'ed client socket value.  You should be using a separate variable to accept the client, and then `close()` both sockets when finished.

Also, the `GetfileSize()` function in your Windows code is leaking the `HANDLE` opened by `CreateFile()`. You need to call `CloseHandle()` before exiting.  Or, you can get the file size without opening the file by using `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()` instead.

Comment: According to your first answer, I have placed the shutdown function before the close function and tested the code again, but the results are still as shown in my question.
For your second answer, as the code I listed was hastily written sample code, there may be situations where the CloseHandle function was not called. In actual code, I called this function. Thank you very much for your reminder.

Comment: Okay, I will try using another socket to store the connection from the sending end. I will modify the code and if there are any issues, I will come back to inform you. thank you.

Comment: I wrote (and still write) lots of networking code, I've never bothered to call shutdown ... indeed, I wrote just now a simple client program without shutdown, tested in Windows 10 and WSL (in Windows 11), and lo and behold, both Wireshark in Windows and tcpdump in Linux show the 4-way handshake

Comment: @zentrunix as I said, on Windows `closesocket()` will handle that internally for you *by default* (the behavior can be disabled), but it is *best practice* to handle it in your code explicitly instead. Even Microsoft says so in their Winsock documentation.

Comment: I have obtained the final answer. This question is not caused by the code I wrote, it is due to poor network status. However, thank you for your answer.